# Type fields versus nested types in .NET

Tags: c#, reflection

For a type, there is the command GetFields() and the command GetNestedTypes().
GetFields()  does not return nested types.
I am confused about the difference between a field and a nested type.
Examples would be very helpful!
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A field is a **variable** of any type that is declared directly in a class or struct. Fields are members of their containing type. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)

and

> A **type** defined within a class or struct is called a nested type. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx)

For instance, in the class

```
class Foo
{
    private int a;

    public class Bar
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

`a` is a field and `Bar` is a nested type.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo {
    private String _aField;

    private class ANestedClass {
        private String _aFieldInANestedClass;
    }
}
```

Like so:

```
public void Blargh() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    FieldInfo aField = foo.GetType().GetField("_aField");
    String aFieldValue = aField.GetValue( foo );

    Type[] nestedTypes = foo.GetType().GetNestedTypes();
    Type aNestedClass = nestedTypes.Single( t => t.Name == "ANestedClass" );
}
```